# How to dynamically iterate on object value using string

Tags: javascript

I have data like this

```
var data = [{"a": "Aditya", "sub": {"v": "result"}}]
```

Now what I want is I get data when i pass props as `a` or `sub.v`

I know I can access data using `data.sub.v` but my `sub.v` is dynamically coming from some service and that is how i want to access the data (it can be any random screen)

Comment: you can iterate objects with Object.entries().

Comment: Yes data[0].sub.v will give it. Question is when I am iterating over data, I need show data in view (The inner content comes from some other service.. so "sub.v" it is coming as string and now over iteration, I want to print "result" as output.

Comment: lodash resolves this problem. Thanks